# Python: plotting an analytic solution to 3rd order

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently reading through a review paper on quintessence and I want to try and reproduce some of their plots and play around with the free parameters. The equations I'm using are:

[image]

and

[image]

I'm trying to get this plot: [image]

However, after playing around with the initial conditions, the best fit I can get is this:

[image]

My method was to simply expand the sum in the equation for w up to n = 3 (but I'm not sure if this is correct), my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w0 = -0.667
omega0 = 0.6

a = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
omega = omega0*(a**(-3.0*w0))/(omega0*(a**(-3.0*w0)) + 1.0 - omega0)
w = w0
for n in range(1,4):
    w += ((((-1.0)**n)*w0*(1.0 - w0**2.0))/(1.0 - (n + 1.0)*w0 + 2.0*n*(n + 1.0)*(w0**2.0)))*((omega/(1.0 - omega))**n)

plt.plot(a,w)
plt.grid(True)
plt.axis([0,1,-0.8,-0.6])
plt.xlabel('a')
plt.ylabel('w')
plt.show()
```

EDIT: My question is why does my code produce a slightly different plot than the one in the paper (note the slight reverse in gradient at the end of the papers plot)? I don't really know if what I'm doing is solving the analytic solution to 1st, 2nd and 3rd order (as stated in the caption of the papers plot)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For starters, use a for loop on the value of `n` to compute `w`. Or you are multiplying your chances of typos by 3 and no one is willing to read through a 1000 character long math experession...

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Julien apologies, I have edited the code to a for loop - running it gives me almost the same plot (only slightly different)

Comment: your `for` loop doesn't do at all what it's supposed to do...

Comment: @PaulH sorry I've edited the post, my question is at the bottom

Comment: @Julien sorry I'm quite new to this and I'm not too sure what kind of for loop I should use for this

Comment: Have edited your question directly to fix your `for` loop since this is not an answer but can't fit into a comment either.  However looks like you still have typos in your formula `(-1)**n` instead of `(-1)**(n-1)` for example... Try to fix them and let me know if you still get "wrong" results.

Comment: @Julien Thanks, I sorted the code out and it gives me still a very similar plot to the one I had - do you know if this method is what is meant when the authors say about solving this equation to 3rd order?

Comment: I can't spot anything obviously wrong, maybe the `w0` and `omega0` you use aren't the same as the one they use...